# how to identify softmask in pdf

Tags: pdf

Is there any scripting/command way to find if there exists any softmask in the entire pdf?As per my understanding softmask is the transparent object in PDF ?.

I have explored some linux based command line like pdfinfo but I need more details about PDF as specified above.

Thanks

Comment: *As per my understanding softmask is the transparent object in PDF ?* - a soft mask is one way to create transparency in a PDF, but there also are transparency groups. That been said, are you only searching for ready-made utilities? Or would you alternatively do some programming, too? In the latter case, which environments?

Comment: I would be doing programming on linux+PHP